# What is the standard OpenGL toolkit?

Tags: opengl, glut, toolkit

I'm just trying to get a grasp on OpenGL that I can build from, so all I'm looking for is something basic to build windows etc. One of the things I'm noticing as I read tutorials and such is that it seems like a lot of the information is out of date - for example a lot of tutorials (many of which were written a number of years ago) refer to using GLUT, but GLUT hasn't been updated in over 10 years - eons in computer time. What do people use nowadays? I know freeglut is out there, but there isn't a whole lot of info on it - how to get it set up, etc... what do most people do? What's the simplest way to get a simple window system up and running so that I can start playing around with OpenGL?

Comment: The OpenGL wiki has a [whole page on getting started with OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Development_Tools). It even has a [page on various OpenGL "toolkits"](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Related_toolkits_and_APIs).

Comment: See [this question for details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936731/why-is-glut-so-bad)

Answer (score 4):

You should first understand the difference between Legacy OpenGL which is a fixed function pipeline, and modern OpenGL which is a completely shader driven pipeline. Most online tutorials teach legacy OpenGL because it is easy to get started and has been around a long time. Legacy still works fine, but you probably want to get into modern OpenGL (at least version 3.0). Modern OpenGL is cleaner, and more flexible, but also harder to get started in, and therefore has fewer tutorials. It requires a lot more setup and libraries by the user and there is no "one way" to do things making it difficult to structure a quick tutorial around.

Some good resources for learning modern OpenGL are:

- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ - Great lessons written by Stack overflow user.
- http://opengles-book.com/ - OpenGL ES 2.0 programming guide - OpenGL ES 2.0 is directly compatible with OpenGL 3.0, so it works great for getting started. Even if you don't want to buy the book you can download sample code which is excellent.
- http://www.swiftless.com/ - Swiftless Tutorials - Great OpenGL 4.0 and WebGL tutorials.

To your main question I know of 3 main libraries for cross platform OpenGL window creation. I would recommend GLFW for a cross platform tool kit. You could also learn a lot by creating a context directly in your respective platform  (WGL window creation on Windows, Cocoa on MacOS X etc) rather than using a windowing library.

1. [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) - you are correct it has not been updated in years. It still works, especially for legacy OpenGL, but I'm not sure how good the modern support is.
2. [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) - Also old and legacy OpenGL (I think this is resolved with 2.0), and includes a lot more cross platform features beyond OpenGL like threads. It is a pretty heavyweight library but I still prefer it over GLUT. A modern, updated SDL was in the works, but i haven't seen anything for it in a long time, possibly discontinued... It also has a nasty license associated with it so watch out for that.
3. [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) - My personal favorite. It is clean and lightweight like GLUT and allows you to target modern OpenGL contexts on most major desktop platforms.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it had changed so much. Is it worthwhile learning the old OpenGL or should I just start with the new stuff? Right now I'm using OpenGL with Qt and the stuff I've been learning has been working, so I'm sure it's not completely useless, but will I pretty much have to start over from scratch when I start learning modern OpenGL? 

Also as far as toolkits, how about GLEW? I saw that one recommended recently; is it something similar?

Comment: @mayonnaise_clinic get on board with the new stuff, don't bother with old. You will have to start over in terms of code but the concepts are mostly the same. I am pretty sure GLEW is just for using OpenGL extensions (mostly need on windows where default headers are for OpenGL 1.1). GLEW is useful for modern OpenGL, but it does not solve context and window creation.

Comment: I have recently started learning to use FreeGLUT as a view layer for physics simulations.  I do not need or want shaders or anything like that, and FreeGLUT is a _perfect_ fit.  So, YMMV!